# Primal/Dual Simplex methods clarification

Tags: duality-theorems, simplex, operations-research

I have several questions regarding these methods.

**Primal Simplex Method**

1. Does the pivot element **always** have to be a *positive* entry in the table?
2. Does the RHS **always** have to be positive in the pivot row?
3. What if I have some negative RHS values?
4. How does the procedure differ if we are looking for MAX or MIN problem?

**Dual Simplex Method**

5. How do I select a pivot row? Do I select whatever negative value on the RHS or the biggest negative in absolute value?
6. Does the pivot element **always** have to be a *negative* entry in the table?
7. Is it allowed for the element in the row of Z to be both positive or negative, but not 0?
8. When performing the ratio test, do I only take care of what **absolute** value is the smallest?
9. How does the procedure differ if we are looking for MAX or MIN problem?

**Example**: Maximize w = -10y1 + 10y2 -15y3

```
 y1     y2     y3     s1     s2     s3     w     RHS
 -1     1      -1     1      0      0      0     -1
 -1     1      1      0      1      0      0     3
 1      -1     -1     0      0      0      0     -3
 -10    10     -15    0      0      0      1     0
```

Now, I assume I take a row with a RHS of **-3** as a pivot row, but how do I choose a pivot column?

The ratios are: (-10/1 = -10); (10/-1 = -10); (-15/-1 = 15); which one do I use?

Comment: **Primal** 1. Yes, 2. Yes, 3. Go to --> Dual Simplex to attempt to restore feasibility, 4. Difference primarily lies in interpretation of result. I'm rusty in dual simplex, so I will defer to others.

Comment: @clocktower When performing a minimum test, what if I have positive RHS value, but negative value in the table (pivot candidate), that I divide with for the ratio? Should this even happen?

Comment: A negative value in the table is never a pivot candidate in the primal simplex algorithm.